# Getting RTCpeerconnection object of participants in twilio video api

Tags: webrtc, twilio

I need to implement signalling between peers in a many to many video conference.
To do that i need access to the RTC Data Channel.
Since "Twilio Video API" [doesn't yet](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-objc/issues/60) provide Data Channel, should I use "Twilio Conversations API" for this task as it provides access to the RTCPeerConnection Object which can be used to create data channels which i found over [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160623235052/https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/04/how-to-use-a-webrtc-peerconnection-in-a-twilio-video-conversation.html):

Or is there a way to get the RTCPeerConnection object of other peers in "Twilio Video API" itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Twilio Conversations API is deprecated so you should not use that.

There's no official way to get access to the `RTCPeerConnection` object within [the Video API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video). I haven't found an unofficial way yet myself (though I'm sure there is, given that JavaScript doesn't really have private methods/properties).

If you definitely need the `RTCDataChannel` itself then you might not want to build with the Twilio Video API.

However, if you are looking to signal between peers, then perhaps the [Twilio Sync API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sync), which is a real time API for syncing data between clients and works really well alongside Twilio Video, can help.

Comment: Thanks @philnash I just want to implement "Raise hand feature" (raise your hand before talking or raise hand to answer yes/no type of polling question). Does [Twilio Video API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video) has an out of the box API to implement this kind of feature?

Comment: Twilio Video does not have an out of the box API for that, no. You could implement that with [Twilio Sync](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sync) though.