# Is it possible to check he bitrate of a twilio video stream?

Tags: html, video, html5-video, twilio

I am developing a video chat application using twilio. I would like to check the bitrate of a video stream playing in the browser to study how the bitrate will be affected at different bandwidths. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can measure various data about the incoming and outgoing streams using the [WebRTC `getStats` API](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc-stats/). There's a really [good article that walks through the available stats](https://testrtc.com/webrtc-internals-parameters/) that you should read to understand it. I would try to write more about it here, but reading the spec and checking out that article will be more accurate and useful to you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: To use getStats api, wouldnt I need access to the `RTCPeerConnection` object? I read in one of your old [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45027499/getting-rtcpeerconnection-object-of-participants-in-twilio-video-api) that the RTCPeerConnection is not accessible using `twiliio-video`. Given that, how can I get information on the actual bandwidth of the video and audio streams in production? The TrackStats from the `room.getStats` function does not have this information.

Comment: What information are you missing? The track stats do include things like `bytesSent` and `packetsSent` on the [`LocalTrackStats`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.7.0/docs/LocalTrackStats.html) and the same for received on [`RemoteTrackStats`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.7.0/docs/RemoteTrackStats.html).

Answer (score 0):

Many videos actually will have variable bit rate, so you can either get an average by simply dividing the file size by the time, or alternatively use a tool like VLC player which will show you the bit rate changing over time (on a Mac it shows the numbers but I believe on Windows it shows a graph):

[image]

If you are more interested in the download bandwidth itself, you can use developer tools in Chrome to see the bit rate.

If you open developer tools and go to the network tab you should see a waterfall column.

Hover over the timeline here in a row that corresponds to your video download and you can see all the details about the request and response including the time it took. The time combined with the size which is also in the row will show you the actual achieved download bit rate.

Here is an example for a YouTube video:

[image]